# print name of parents who have children with same name

Tags: sql, oracle

PARENT table `PK` is PID and PID is `FK` in CHILDREN table. How do I print names of Parents from PARENT table that have children who share the same name as another child in CHILDREN table? I think a recursive join should be used to find the same name but I can't get it to work. I am able to `join` the PARENT and CHILDREN tables using below query:

```
select PARENT.NAME as ParentName
from PARENT inner join CHILDREN
on PARENT.PID=CHILDREN.PID
group by NAME;
```

I have tried this query to complete the recursive join but it isn't working:

```
select CHILDREN.NAME
from CHILDREN e, CHILDREN m
where e.CHILDREN.PID=m.CHILDREN.PID 
order by CHILDREN.PID;
```

Comment: Not clear what you are looking for.  You want parents who have children with the same name as eachother?  Or parents who have the same name as their children?

Comment: Please describe the tables (column names, relationship, test data). Normally a child has two parents, therefore I guess there should exist two entries in the parents table per child?

Comment: query is looking for parents who have children that have the same name as another child. So parentA and parentB who have child named childA. @Frank table CHILDREN (ChildName, PID (FK)) and table PARENT (PID(PK),ParentName). This is only considering a single parent to single child relationship.

Answer (score 1):

Group by child name and evaluate, if at least two different parents exist.

```
-- TEST DATA
with parent(pid, name) as
 (select 1, 'Parent1' from dual
  union all
  select 2, 'Parent2' from dual
  union all
  select 3, 'Parent3' from dual
  union all
  select 4, 'Parent4' from dual),
children(name, pid) as
 (select 'Tom', 1 from dual
  union all
  select 'Tim', 1 from dual
  union all 
  select 'Steven', 2 from dual
  union all
  select 'Tim', 2 from dual
  union all
  select 'Marta', 2 from dual
  union all
  select 'Jess', 3 from dual
  union all
  select 'Jim', 4 from dual
  union all
  select 'Jess', 4 from dual)

--> SELECT
select c.name, listagg(p.name, ',') within group(order by p.name)
  from parent p
  join children c
    on c.pid = p.pid
 group by c.name -- group by child name
having min (p.pid) <> max (p.pid) -- at least two different parents


--> RESULT
Jess    Parent3,Parent4
Tim     Parent1,Parent2
```

Answer (score 0):

AND Parent.Name = Children.Name
So wouldn't this print names of the parents where it matches with Children's names?

Comment: I'm looking for parents who have children that share a name with another child, not a parent who shares a name with their child.